# Spotlight with Halo applied is creating rings around light

Tags: light

Here's a portion of a render I'm working on, which is backlit from behind by a spotlight with a "Halo" effect applied:

[image: Spotlight with halo]

If you look carefully in the background, you'll notice the halo effect is creating "rings" of shadow as it fades.  How can I remove these rings and make the halo effect fade out smoothly?  I've played around with all the settings I can find without any success.

Here's my current settings for the spotlight:

[image: Spotlight settings]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a dithering problem. Which is not really a problem at all, but rather what physically must happen. That occurs any time there is a small change in color spread over a large area.

One of the ways to get rid of the banding is to make a stronger contrast, such as a pure black background.

The best way to deal with it. Is under the `Render` tab in the `Properties` window. Set the dithering amount up a bit until the color banding is not visible.

[image: post processing dither]