# Choppy gradients in baked lightmaps

Tags: light, texture-baking

I've modeled some interiors and lighted them with a simple area light.
I'm currently trying to bake the lighting to a lightmap that I can then import into Unity3D Free Version (which doesn't have very good lighting for interiors, and that's why I'm making the lightmaps on blender).
However, the baked lightmap seems to be poor in quality even though I made the texture 2048x2048. It's kinda hard to explain, but basically the gradients are choppy, as if the image was compressed. This is very subtle if I look at the lightmap itself on paint (albeit still visible), but the effect is magnified once the lightmap is applied to a colored material on unity3d:
[image]

My baking settings:
[image]

Comment: See my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6489/2217)

Comment: Thank you! So I'm assuming I'll have to manually apply dithering on the exported lightmap texture before I import it into unity, as blender doesn't seem to apply it to the baked lightmap.