# Is it possible to use filmic and raw in a single video?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color, color-management, filmic-blender

I am currently doing a motion tracking scene where the compositing looks like this :

[image: Compositing nodes]

The problem I am facing at is that I want my foreground layer to be rendered with a View Transform that is `Filmic` and my movie clip with a `raw` one.
Here is the difference :

[image: Clip color difference]
[image: Ball color difference]

Obviously, the `filmic` mode for the movie clip is removing all the colors but it's perfect for the rendering of the ball.
If I change the View Transform parameter in the Scene color managment, it's changing it for the whole scene.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your images are in two very different color spaces.  You will have to render the CG element as images using filmic and then composite the result using the color space used for the video file. You shouldn't be using RAW as color transform, but the appropriate color space (likely sRGB or rec709). Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134893/blender-dosnt-interpret-the-colorspace-of-the-imported-image-in-the-compositor/134939#134939 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107303/white-background-turning-grey-during-video-creation/107308#107308

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer !