# Question about shading color

Tags: shaders

[image]

The left is the color I paint in Texture paint. The right is the color shown on my model. It is so different. Please help why the two-color are different.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164679/88681

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/how-to-get-accurate-colors-with-filmic-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134893/blender-dosnt-interpret-the-colorspace-of-the-imported-image-in-the-compositor