# Why is my backround image distorting when rendered as animation?

Tags: rendering

[image]

When i am rendering a 250 frame animation the still jog backround gets these weird streaks. Im using blender 2.79. Never had a his problem before but this is my first time using a jpg as backround... please help

Comment: Do a search for [color banding](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+banding&oq=color+bandin&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0j69i60l3.2731j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Seems like this will fix it ill let you know how it goes. Aside from bitrate and jitter adjustments could this also be due to blenders new file compression options? I was using the slowest option for highest compressoon... just a thought. Thanks for the sweet tip though!

Comment: Banding ([quantization error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)))is a problem that clearly shows the limits of working on a low bit depth. There are not enough tones to represent the subtle change of similar colors of the sky. Work with higher bit originals and render at a higher bit as well. you can disguise some of those errors by changing the values for dithering in The Post Process tab see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29218/how-to-avoid-gradient-banding-while-using-a-video-sequence-editor and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/default-cube-rendered-with-line-artefacts/74857#74857