# Better quality blur in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to get rid of an artifact in my compositor setup:

[image]

I get these rings:

[image]

Is this a range problem with the information coming out of the nodes? Or is it a limitation in the image type/display?

Comment: Have the same problem with the smoothness of colors transition after rendering the gradient texture. Thanks for asking this question :).

Comment: I suspect it's a limitation with the number of colours the output image can represent; I tried running the output of the ColourRamp (shown here) through an additional blur which didn't fix it :/

Comment: Those rings are called "color banding". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding . Your display cannot resolve the subtle differences needed for a clean color gradient. A workarond is to increase the dithering values for rendering. read: http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/dither.html?highlight=dithering

Comment: related: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/14570/6685

Comment: This is one of those cases where noise can be your friend...

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles/5800#5800 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/spotlight-with-halo-applied-is-creating-rings-around-light/6489#6489

Comment: Note that this is a blurred ellipse mask in the compositor, not a render.

Comment: It is a limitation of the color depth. Gradients appear "stepped" when they are spread out over large areas and there is not enough bit depth to accurately represent the gradient transition. The first step (no pun intended) would be switching your color depth from 8 to 16 in your render settings. Also follow the advice in the comments others have posted above - basically saying the same thing in a different way, whether you call it "color banding" or "gradient stepping".